# Merging Divs Within Block

Tags: html, css

If you look at my Fiddle below, I am trying to add the social buttons to the right side of the block containing the logo.  I've got to the point where I can get them both in the same block, however, the social buttons appear below the logo.  As it stands, the social buttons and logo are appearing in separate blocks.  I'm still a little "wet behind the ears" when it comes to coding so, pardon my naivety if this is an easy fix.  Thanks for taking a look and I appreciate your time.

My Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Del087/angk8v6z/3/

The CSS

```
div {
background-color: #080808;
display: inline-block;
width: 950px;
padding: 10px;
margin: 5px;
}
#social a:hover {
background-color: transparent;
opacity:0.7;
}
#social img {
-moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
#social img:hover {
-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
-o-transform: rotate(360deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

The HTML

```
    <div style="display: inline-block;"><a href="http://s1314.photobucket.com/user/RTH13/media/RTH%20Artwork/RTHTextLogo1_zpsfd100146.png.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/RTH%20Artwork/RTHTextLogo1_zpsfd100146.png" border="0" alt=" photo RTHTextLogo1_zpsfd100146.png"/></a>

</div>
<div id="social" style="display: inline-block;"> <a href=" http://www.twitter.com/realtimehockey1 " target="_blank "><img border="0 " src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Website%20Art/twitter_zpsb3e89d7a.png " style="margin-right:1px; " alt="Follow Us On Twitter " title="Follow Us On Twitter "/></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the other div inside the parent one and update div css to be applied only to the parent.

```
        <div class="parent" style="display: inline-block;"><a href="http://s1314.photobucket.com/user/RTH13/media/RTH%20Artwork/RTHTextLogo1_zpsfd100146.png.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/RTH%20Artwork/RTHTextLogo1_zpsfd100146.png" border="0" alt=" photo RTHTextLogo1_zpsfd100146.png"/></a>
<div id="social" style="display: inline-block;"> <a href=" http://www.twitter.com/realtimehockey1 " target="_blank "><img border="0 " src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Website%20Art/twitter_zpsb3e89d7a.png " style="margin-right:1px; " alt="Follow Us On Twitter " title="Follow Us On Twitter "/></a>

<a href="http://www.facebook.com/realtimehockey " target="_blank "><img border="0 " src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Website%20Art/facebook-square_zpsebe7308f.png " style="margin-right:1px; " alt="Like Us On Facebook " title="Like Us On Facebook "/></a>

<a href="http://www.instagram.com/realtimehockey " target="_blank "><img style="margin-right:1px; " src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Website%20Art/instagram_zps74a97e79.png " alt="Follow Us On Instagram " title="Follow Us On Instagram "/></a>

<a href="Contact Us " target="_blank "><img style="margin-right:1px; " src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Website%20Art/email_zps98fe1c68.png " alt="Contact Us " title="Contact Us "/></a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS -

```
div.parent {
    background-color: #080808;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 950px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}
#social{
 float: right;   
}    
#social a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    opacity:0.7;
}
#social img {
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
#social img:hover {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

See the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/angk8v6z/4/

Comment: Why not move the #social inline-block in to the CSS rather than HTML.  Or is it just me that can't stand that.  Typo two right curly brackets after #social

Comment: typo corrected but I am not able to understand your other question.

Comment: I find inline CSS in the HTML to be very annoying especially when there is CSS for the same tag in the `<style>` .   There is a #social in the `<style>` and then there is `<div id="social" style="display: inline-block;` in the HTML.  I understand it was not you.  Just a pet peeve, I'm old and cranky.  One of those days.

Comment: Yes one should not do this but most of the time people don't really care as long as things working good.

Answer (score 1):

Place the social div inside the banner's div and make it's display inline, and I think it does exactly what you asked.  I also recommend instead of styling all of divs (`div{}`), add a class to the banner div and style that one directly.  Lastly, the `inline-block` on the banner div is no longer needed

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/trex005/angk8v6z/5/

Comment: if you want the social icons floating right :
http://jsfiddle.net/trex005/angk8v6z/6/

Answer (score -1):

This is really bad.  The following applies to all `<div>`

```
div {
background-color: #080808;
display: inline-block;
width: 950px;
padding: 10px;
margin: 5px;
}
```

Then if you have CSS styles you should not be using in line styles

```
<div style="display: inline-block;">
```

I really do not want to look further.  Need to get the Basic stuff right first.

Comment: You can comment with why you feel the question needs work, but to give an answer that is not an answer just complaining about the question is only making things worse.

Comment: No it was not the question it was the horrific CSS.  The `div{` was too much for me.  You have more patience than me. When the basic CSS is that horrific I do not feel like feeding someone fish when they would be better served by learning how to fish.  I do like your solution.  Nice and elegant.  I was considering deleting my answer because I was sure someone would down vote it. But I wanted to see if anyone would down vote it. I'm old and cranky.